# Keep getting the same error. "Invalid syntax" Very new to programming Python

Tags: python, syntax, menu

Here's the code that appears to have the problem:

```
elif answer == 2:
        students = ["Jonny Butler", "Harry Tennent", "Rashid Talha"]
        if raw_input("Which student are you looking for?") == students[0]:
            print "Jonny Butler," " Age: 15,"" Medical Condition: Asthma"
            elif raw_input("Which student are you looking for?") == students[1]:
                print "Harry Tennent, " "Age: 14, " "Medical Condition: None"
            elif raw_input("Which student are you looking for?") == students[2]:
                print "Rashid Talha, " "Age: 16, " "Medical Condition: None"
            else:
                print "Sorry, we don\'t appear to have that student on out database!"
```

The error keeps saying that "line 30" has an invalid syntax:

```
File "<stdin>", line 30 elif answer == 2: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax Unknown error
```

any help would be great, I'm very new to Python.

Comment: This is the error: File "<stdin>", line 30
    elif answer == 2:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Unknown error.

Comment: Your code is going to ask the user more times than it should. "Who are you looking for? Wasn't the first guy. Who are you looking for? Wasn't the second guy. Who are you looking for? ..." all the way until it finds a match.

Comment: This is desperate for a dictionary `patients = {"Jonny Butler": {"Age": 15, "Medical Condition": "Asthma"}, ...}`, then you can easily get the patients' details by name: `if name in patients: details = patients[name]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You should make an answer out of that. It is always refreshing to see another approach :)

Comment: @Kraay89 alright, done!

Comment: For God! Why that could be considered as off-topic??? He has SYNTAX problem, and further shortening will spoil the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yup, *not* by name though, as soon as there are two patients named John Smith or Mohammed this will fail badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This becomes much more efficient if you use a dictionary:

```
elif answer == 2:
    students = {"Jonny Butler": {"Age": 15, "Condition": "Asthma"}, 
                "Harry Tennent": {"Age": 14, "Condition": None},
                "Rashid Talha": {"Age": 16, "Condition": None}}
    name = raw_input("Which student are you looking for?")
    if name in students:
        details = students[name]
        print "{0}, Age: {1[Age]}, Medical Condition: {1[Condition]}".format(name, details)
    else:
        print "Sorry, we don't appear to have that student on our database!"
```

The reduction in repeated code makes it much less likely you will make a mistake (like the previous asking for input on every `elif`). Separating the data (`students`) from the display (`print`) also means you can reuse the data elsewhere more easily.

Comment: Come to think of it, You still look up a value twice. Maybe with a `try`/`except KeyError` statement, one could further reduce the number of operations? Correct me if i'm wrong. Though this might be out of scope, as the OP is very new to python, and maybe not ready for exception handling yet.

Comment: It's probably slightly less efficient, but It's not a big consideration here and, as you say, exception handling might be too much, too soon.

Comment: The online interpreter i used to test this, always fails, even if name in dictionary. If i modify to typecast to string, it works, if I don't but let it print the name before checking, it does work aswel. Not sure if it's the online interpreter messing up, or minor improvement is needed? I can't test it in a decent IDE right now. (http://repl.it/) --- Nevermind, i just checked with another online interpreter, and it runs fine

Comment: I get that some times with online interpreters that some fail to carry out simple bits of code and others run it fine. Temperamental...

Answer (score 1):

The `elif` statements after the `if` are not indented properly. And probably you should ask for the user input only once:

```
elif answer == 2:
        students = ["Jonny Butler", "Harry Tennent", "Rashid Talha"]
        inp = raw_input("Which student are you looking for?")
        if inp == students[0]:
            print "Jonny Butler," " Age: 15,"" Medical Condition: Asthma"
        elif inp == students[1]:
            print "Harry Tennent, " "Age: 14, " "Medical Condition: None"
        elif inp == students[2]:
            print "Rashid Talha, " "Age: 16, " "Medical Condition: None"
        else:
            print "Sorry, we don\'t appear to have that student on out database!"
```